# Thermaltake PSU button won't stay in the "on" position

Tags: power-supply, hardware-failure

My [Thermaltake Toughpower Grand 750W PSU](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817153132) (P/N TPG-750M like on their web page, but the design shown below) has a mechanical AC push button rather than an on/off switch, and after turning it off today to change some hardware it won't stay on after pushing again (So yes, I've tried turning it off and on again, and I've made sure it's plugged in). In fact, I had to jam it on with a piece of plastic against some furniture to make it stay on, which is not a tenable situation.

It *might* still be under warranty, but I'd like to know first if this could be the result of some sort of **safeguard** and if there are any **quick fixes** for it. Holding it in place may be an option, but it would have to be done without blocking the air flow.

Jamming the button with the thin end of a strip seal works for now...

[image: PSU with button]

Comment: Sounds like a physical defect to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has a 5 year warrantee on parts and labor. So if your time frame is within that five years, I do not know that I would do something that may void that.

I have always had a good experience with their customer service and the touching base with a tech would at least start the ball rolling if an RMA is required.

[Thermaltake customer Support](http://my.thermaltake.com/usa/)

Comment: Looks like it's actually [7 years' warranty](http://my.thermaltake.com/csWarranty.aspx). I'll try contacting them, thanks!