# PSU replacement made the whole PC fail

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

What happened is a long story, but I'll try to be as short as possible. My PC failed without warning yesterday, I suspected my PSU (an Antec HCG 520w), so I bought a new one (Corsair RM 650w) and I installed it. The system seemed to work fine, but there was no image on my screen... After researching a bit I couldnt find anything, but now my PC is doing some weird sounds (pretty sure they come from the motherboard. It beeps once like always, followed by a second weird beep). My motherboard has an UEFI and I cant seem to find the beeping codes anywhere... It's an Asus P8Z68-V LX.

Here is a video I made of what is happening, hope it helps. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D-hVN7suoaI&feature=youtube_gdata_player

Thanks by advance.

Comment: Do you get an image when you connect to the on-board graphics device? What was the previous failure? It simply didn't turn on anymore? Also see http://superuser.com/questions/618064/how-do-i-interpret-the-asus-motherboard-led-and-beep-patterns

Comment: Did you read the manual of your motherboard to find the reason behind the weird beep sound?

Comment: I only hear one beep which almost indicates it is are to post.  Do you have a graphics card if so are all requires cables plugged I .  Describe the original problem