# How to interpret Lite-On DVD drive blink pattern?

Tags: dvd

I've got a [Lite-On LH-20A1S](http://www.cnet.com/products/liteon-lh-20a1s-dvdrw-r-dl-dvd-ram-drive-serial-ata-series/specs/) which has been working fine for years. I haven't used it for a while, and now it just blinks at me if I put a video DVD in it: **two blinks, repeated three times.** I get no new messages in `dmesg` or `journalctl` at this point. I've tried:

- Rebooting
- Using a bit of spray duster
- Attempting to use it on both Windows and Linux.
- Loading several different DVDs (including several brand new ones and one old professional video DVD)

It's perfectly able to read CDs.

From `dmesg`:

```
ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
ata1.00: ATAPI: LITE-ON DVDRW LH-20A1S, 9L09, max UDMA/100
ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
scsi 0:0:0:0: CD-ROM            LITE-ON  DVDRW LH-20A1S   9L09 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
sr 0:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi3-mmc drive: 48x/48x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
sr 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
```

Comment: have you tried another brand of dvds?

Comment: I've never heard of read LEDs meaning anything on a dvd drive

Comment: @JourneymanGeek It is very common for LEDs on various hardware to be used to signal error conditions. Sadly, these are often undocumented or at least [hard to find](https://superuser.com/q/618064/2259).

Comment: So it can read, just not burn? Usually means a malfunction which cannot be repaired at a low cost, much cheaper to replace it. I have had a few of these do this to me.

Comment: No, it can read only CDs, not DVDs.